# jsonschema.exceptions- Unknown type 'str' for validator with schema:

Tags: python, flask, swagger, jsonschema, connexion

I used `flask` and `connexion` for my api, I got python server stub from swagger editor and it was generated based on api spec. However, one of my endpoint make request with `json` data, it should be validated by json schema validator. I used `jsonschema` python library for that. But, now when I test endpoint with sample json data, I got following exception:

```
>     (env) C:\Users\kim\imm_python_server>python -m test_server
>      * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
>      * Environment: production
>        WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
>        Use a production WSGI server instead.
>      * Debug mode: off
>      * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:07] "[37mGET /api/v1/ui/ HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:07] "[37mGET /api/v1/ui/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:07] "[37mGET /api/v1/openapi.json HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:13] "[1m[31mGET /api/v1/about HTTP/1.1[0m" 401 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:25] "[37mGET /api/v1/about HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
>     C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\flask_api.py:199:
> FutureWarning: Implicit (flask) JSON serialization will change in the
> next major version. This is triggered because a response body is being
> serialized as JSON even though the mimetype is not a JSON type. This
> will be replaced by something that is mimetype-specific and may raise
> an error instead of silently converting everything to JSON. Please
> make sure to specify media/mime types in your specs.
>       FutureWarning  # a Deprecation targeted at application users.
>     127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 20:14:38] "[37mGET /api/v1/rsession HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
>     [2020-05-18 20:14:50,506] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1/immunomatch_ed [POST]
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app
>         response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception
>         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
>         raise value
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.dispatch_request()
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request
>         return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\decorator.py",
> line 48, in wrapper
>         response = function(request)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\security.py",
> line 327, in wrapper
>         return function(request)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\uri_parsing.py",
> line 144, in wrapper
>         response = function(request)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\validation.py",
> line 158, in wrapper
>         self.validate_schema(data, request.url)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\validation.py",
> line 195, in validate_schema
>         self.validator.validate(data)
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py",
> line 122, in validate
>         for error in self.iter_errors(*args, **kwargs):
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py",
> line 98, in iter_errors
>         for error in errors:
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_validators.py",
> line 291, in properties_draft4
>         schema_path=property,
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py",
> line 114, in descend
>         for error in self.iter_errors(instance, schema):
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py",
> line 98, in iter_errors
>         for error in errors:
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\json_schema.py",
> line 64, in validate_type
>         if not any(validator.is_type(instance, type) for type in types):
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\json_schema.py",
> line 64, in <genexpr>
>         if not any(validator.is_type(instance, type) for type in types):
>       File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py",
> line 127, in is_type
>         raise UnknownType(type, instance, self.schema)
>     jsonschema.exceptions.UnknownType:
>     Unknown type 'str' for validator with schema, While checking instance:0
```

**my python dependencies**

here is my python depencies:

> ```
> connexion == 2.6.0
> swagger-ui-bundle == 0.0.2
> python_dateutil == 2.6.0
> setuptools >= 21.0.0
> Werkzeug==0.16.1
> ```

I quite don't understand why I got this error, I believe it is bug from `jsonschema`. How can I get this going right? anyone have possible guess what's going on with this? any thought? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue usually comes when the provided type is unregistered for validation. In your case, it's `str`. JSON Schema provides OOTB support for few types like string, boolean, etc, check

```
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html
```

For the rest of the types, you have to write your own custom validator.

Comment: can you elaborate your thought with possible attempt I might try? thanks